# How can i fix (node:1024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined in nodejs

Tags: discord.js

the error is from this line:

```
    if (!args[1].includes("m","h","d","mo","y")) return message.channel.send("That is not a vaild time.")
```

I tried:

```
  if (!args[1].includes(["m","h","d","mo","y"])) return message.channel.send("That is not a vaild time.")
```

but it didn't work too

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please include your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `args[1]` is undefined

Comment: you could check if args is an array, if it is an array you can check if it has length >= 2 before accessing the index: args[1]

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `args.includes`, I believe args[1] returns as something different